# How to deal with convergence warning when using LinearSVC in sklearn?

Tags: python, scikit-learn, svm

I got a convergence warning using linear support vector machine in Scikit learn with breast cancer data.

Below is the code:

```py
from sklearn.svm import LinearSVC
from sklearn.datasets import load_breast_cancer

cancer = load_breast_cancer()
(X_cancer, y_cancer) = load_breast_cancer(return_X_y = True)
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X_cancer, y_cancer, random_state = 0)

clf = LinearSVC(max_iter=700000).fit(X_train, y_train)
print('Breast cancer dataset')
print('Accuracy of Linear SVC classifier on training set: {:.2f}'
     .format(clf.score(X_train, y_train)))
print('Accuracy of Linear SVC classifier on test set: {:.2f}'
     .format(clf.score(X_test, y_test)))
```

Even with ultra high number of iterations, I still got Convergence Warning:

> ConvergenceWarning: Liblinear failed to converge, increase the number
> of iterations.   warnings.warn("Liblinear failed to converge, increase
> "

Can any one explain why it cannot converge? And, generally, can I just ignore Convergence warning, or do I need to further tune the model?

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

svm methods are distance based, and your columns are on different scales. so it makes sense to scale the data first before fitting the model. See more at post such as [this](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/154224/when-using-svms-why-do-i-need-to-scale-the-features) or [this](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/118092/why-does-the-scaling-of-feature-vectors-improve-performance-of-svm-classifier)

So if we do it again with scaling :

```
from sklearn.svm import LinearSVC
from sklearn.datasets import load_breast_cancer
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler

cancer = load_breast_cancer()
(X_cancer, y_cancer) = load_breast_cancer(return_X_y = True)
X_cancer = StandardScaler().fit_transform(X_cancer)

X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X_cancer, y_cancer, random_state = 0)

clf = LinearSVC().fit(X_train, y_train)
```

You get a pretty good accuracy without the convergence issue:

```
print('Accuracy of Linear SVC classifier on training set: {:.2f}'
     .format(clf.score(X_train, y_train)))
print('Accuracy of Linear SVC classifier on test set: {:.2f}'
     .format(clf.score(X_test, y_test)))

Accuracy of Linear SVC classifier on training set: 0.99
Accuracy of Linear SVC classifier on test set: 0.94
```

Comment: Thank you!. Feature normalization is one solution, and in this case, it worked well. Do you know what are the other typical methods to deal with convergence warnings? Also, just wanted to point out a minor problem in your code - training the scalar object should be on the training data only and completely excluding the test data. Otherwise, it would bring in data leakage problem. Test data should be transformed by scalar that trained solely on training data.

Comment: convergence usually boils down to the model having problems fitting and finding a global solution, or achieving so called tolerance https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/255375/what-exactly-is-tol-tolerance-used-as-stopping-criteria-in-sklearn-models. Simplest case is that something is wrong with the input, more complicated cases would be a lot of noise..

Comment: sure, you can scale the data in whatever way you like, to prevent data leakage